# How do I remove odd-valued elements from an array?

Tags: java, arrays

My objective is to write a method that creates a copy of an array with the odd numbers removed. Here is my code:

```
public class Evens {
    static int[] evens(int[] input) {
        final int n = input.length;
        int[] output = new int[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if(input[i]%2 == 0)
                output[i] = input[i];
        }
        return output;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] fvalues = new int[] {4,7,9,3,6,8,2};
        int[] evalues = evens(fvalues);
        for(int i=0;i<evalues.length;i++)
            System.out.println(i+"] "+evalues[i]);
    }
}
```

When I run it, It gives me the elements of an array with all the even numbers of the original array but with zeros where the odd numbers were. How can I write it so there are no zeros with the odd numbers just gone?

Comment: Please tag as homework if it is.

Comment: Yes, it is. I've added the tag.

Answer (score 1):

For removing an element you're better off using an `ArrayList`, since an array can't change its size. If you *have to* use arrays, then the `output` array must be shorter than the `input`. Say, if you're going to remove three elements, then the size of `output` will have to be `input.length-3`.

In your implementation, you're not actually *removing* elements, you just skip over the odd numbers, and since an `int[]` is initialized by default to zeros, the places where the odd numbers used to be appear with zeros on them.

You can do this:

1. Calculate the number of even elements
2. Create a new output array with the length found on the previous step
3. Copy only the even numbers to the output array. It's a bit tricky, since you'll need to use *two* indexes (but only a single for loop): one index for iterating over the input array, and the other for iterating over the output array - the index for the input array gets incremented as usual, for every step of the iteration, but the index for the output array gets incremented *only* after adding a new even element to the output.

Comment: I need it to work with any length array, so I need it to be general.

Comment: @DylanBroussard - Oscar's just giving you an example to help you figure out your algorithm. The third paragraph is a good suggestion.

Comment: @DylanBroussard I edited my answer adding more details, that's as far as I can go since it's a homework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you constrained by memory here (reqt. of this homework)?

I would do this (to make it little challenging).

1. For every element you need to remove, set this element as '0' or some non existing no. (lets call this 'A' for ex.) in the array.
2. Once you have this updated original array, now start overwriting all 'A' in this array with the next valid element( ex. A 1 2 A 4 5 A 6 should become 1 2 4 5 6 A A A). You may have to act on multiple 'A' occurrences at some point
3. either you can print this array till you hit A (working with in the same memory constraints) or copy to a new array with the required elements.

This process although is complex would give some real practice as part of homework.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't indicate if you have any restrictions as to the type of algorithm you can use.  Assuming that you have the freedom to do whatever you want, I would suggest using a `List` to store the even values as you iterate over your complete array, and copy any even numbers to the list.

There are several different `List` implementations that you can use.  I will leave it up to you to do a little legwork and determine which one(s) can best be used.  Hint - check the JavaDocs for implementing classes of `List`.

Once you have a complete `List` with all the even numbers, it is a fairly trivial exercise to convert that back into an array with the `toArray` method.  Again, I will leave it to you to do a little legwork to find examples as to how to use the method.  Hint - there are several posts on StackOverflow that use it.

If you are limited to the type of structures you can use, and can only use arrays, then it will likely need to be a multi-pass process, in which you use a separate index for your "even" array and once done, you need to recopy the array to a properly-sized final array.

As a final suggestion, instead of using an index'ed for loop to loop through your full array, you can use Java 5+ for-each enhanced loop syntax and simplify your indexing needs.  Ex:

```
for(int value : input ){
  if( value % 2 == 0 ) 
     // do something
}
```

This will eliminate at least one confusing index.  As a fun exercise, see if you can code your function without needing any loop indexes using some of the suggestions I've made above.

If there is something unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You have to consider that the fields of an array of a primitive type like int cant't be null, empty or something similar, they have to be an integer number (in your case 0).

Also the size of an array is fixed from the time of its declaration on and can't be changed in the future.

When you want to generate an array that contains only the even numbers of your list you are talking of an array with less fields i.e. a smaller size, so i guess it's quite clear that you have to generate a new array to solve you assignment...

some simple hints:

```
public class Evens {
    static int[] evens(int[] input) {
        final int n = input.length;

        int[] output = new int[n];

        // consider adding some additional lines

        }
        // return ...
        // hint: use something slightly different that your output array
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         int[] fvalues = new int[] {4,7,9,3,6,8,2};
         int[] evalues = evens(fvalues);
         for(int i=0;i<evalues.length;i++)
             System.out.println(i+"] "+evalues[i]);
    }
```

Comment: This question is tagged as homework.  Please provide direction and not a full answer.

Comment: It was not when i answered the question !

Comment: It wasn't tagged as homework until a minute ago. After Marc answered.

Comment: Even if it wasn't a homework question, it's poor quality since there's only code and no explanation.

Comment: I stand corrected.  I retracted my downvote, but I believe PaulBellora has a point.

Comment: Not trying to be a jerk here - just pointing out how it could be improved under normal circumstances. But given that we know it's homework now, it should be edited to not spoon-feed the answer.

Comment: Even if it weren't homework (meaning: you shouldn't post the solution, only hints, ideas) the above code doesn't work, it has compilation errors. After fixing the compilation errors ... it _still_ doesn't work.